# Server-side Framework/Language for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

If MySQL walks hand-in-hand with PHP, what is the equivalent of the MongoDB? Is there any framework that works efficiently and matured with MongoDB?

Comment: The great thing about the MongoDb community is that there are lots of great drivers that have been adapted for many different programming languages and frameworks, so you can safely select one that matches your environment and skills without much worry.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any platform for which MongoDB driver is provided - and there are plenty. Here is the list of all mongo drivers for  platforms:

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/

I would say, MongoDB is more frequently used with such platforms as node.js as mongo has JSON-ish query syntax, thus JS-devs like it more than SqlServer or Oracle. But it doesn't mean that it can't be used or has some limitations for other platforms. I use MongoDB on my .NET projects and it all works just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

"walks hand-in-hand"? If you mean MySQL drivers exist for PHP then yes, similar drivers exist for MongoDB: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php

On top of this most PHP frameworks have support for MongoDB, including:

- Kohana
- CakePHP
- Yii
- Symfony
- Laravel
- Doctrine ODM (not a framework but higher enough level to mention)
- Zend
- Lithium

The list is endless and all of these frameworks have mature plugins, I personally have actually developed a very mature plugin for Yii which works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

did u look at this ?

[php class for mongodb: visit the hyperlink](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php)

Answer (score 0):

Most languages have mongodb support via drivers provided.

Here is the list of all drivers: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/

As of popular combo equivalent, MongoDB is pretty popular among node.js based back-ends, especially with the mongoose driver.

Comment: I'd say node.js is still not enough mature as web framework. Check out Python. It's easy to start with. And of course there is mongo driver for python - PyMongo.

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich I just found out that Django-nonrel is there for MongoDB. Do you have any experience using it? What is your recommendation?

Comment: @HaikalNashuha Node.js is NOT a framework. Its a programming platform, a construction kit to MAKE new frameworks.